# Python(3.x) - Opening File and Removing the Quotation Marks when reading file

Tags: python, python-3.x, openfiledialog, filedialog

I'm currently trying to load a .txt file that has the following inside the file:

['Chest', ['bench', 'incline'], [2, 1], [10, 10], [10, 20, 10]], 'Chest', ['decline'], [1], [1], [10]

When I load the file, read the information on the file and store it on a variable named `content`:

```
    self.file_name = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    if self.file_name is None:
        return
    with open(self.file_name) as f:
        content = f.read().splitlines()
```

When I print out content:

```
    print(content)
```

I get the following output:

`["['Chest', ['bench', 'incline'], [2, 1], [10, 10], [10, 20, 10]], 'Chest', ['decline'], [1], [1], [10]"]`

The problem is that there's quotation marks when it prints. Could there be anyway to get rid of the ""? The reason is because since it's a two dimensonal list and `print([0][1])` I get the result of ' instead of `chest`

Comment: You can replace strings as follows: `a_str.replace('"','')`. Not sure if this is what you are after. Please confirm.

Comment: @Marcin I cant seem to figure out where `a_str.replace('"','')` would go in my code.. Does it go after the line  `content =....`?

Comment: And this one? `content[0].replace('"','')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your content contains syntax representing correct python literal code, you can parse it directly into python data:

```
content = ["['Chest', ['bench', 'incline'], [2, 1], [10, 10], [10, 20, 10]], 'Chest', ['decline'], [1], [1], [10]"]

import ast
a_tuple = ast.literal_eval(content[0])
print(a_tuple)
```

Results in a tupple containing the parased string:

```
(['Chest', ['bench', 'incline'], [2, 1], [10, 10], [10, 20, 10]], 'Chest', ['decline'], [1], [1], [10])
```

Comment: Where are you getting `ast.` from? When I do this I get the following error: `NameError: name 'ast' is not defined`

Comment: ast is standard python module. Import it `import ast`. Link is [here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/ast.html).

Answer (score 0):

`print(content[0])`

The `content` variable is holding an array of a single string. When you did `print(content[0][1])`, you printed the second character of the string. When printing a string, the outer quotes are not shown, but when printing an array, the outer quotes are shown (so you can see where each string begins and ends).

Comment: When I do this, I get the result of `['Chest', ['bench', 'incline'], [2, 1], [10, 10], [10, 20, 10]], 'Chest', ['cola'], [1], [1], [10]` since it's a two dimensional list. I dont get the result of just `Chest`

Comment: It's a string that looks like a two dimensional list. It's not a two dimensional list. You'd need to transform it into one first.

Comment: @Havyy I see what you mean, but how exactly would I transform it into a two dimensional?